# extract string have dot using regex substr oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

Input string:

(`select FRL_ATTRIBUTE_DESCRIPTION from  FRL_ATTRIBUTES WHERE FRL_ATTRIBUTE_LEVEL =9 AND FRL_Lines_PL.FRL_ATTRIBUTE_09 = FRL_ATTRIBUTE`)

Ouput :

```
FRL_Lines_PL.FRL_ATTRIBUTE_09
```

i need to extract `FRL_Lines_PL.FRL_ATTRIBUTE_09` alias name string using `regex_substr`

Comment: Which alias name - do you mean you only want the `FRL_Lines_PL` part *before* the dot? What if there is no dot? Or you want the string you have shown because that is a fragment that has a dot in it? Again, what if there is no dot; or multiple fragments with dots? Please edit your question to explain and show the output you expect, and preferably what you have tried and what issues you have.

Answer (score 1):

You said you want to extract a string that contains a dot and provided example. OK, if that's exactly what you have & need, then

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '(select FRL_ATTRIBUTE_DESCRIPTION from FRL_ATTRIBUTES WHERE FRL_ATTRIBUTE_LEVEL =9 AND FRL_Lines_PL.FRL_ATTRIBUTE_09 = FRL_ATTRIBUTE)' from dual)
  3  select regexp_substr(col, '\w+\.\w+') result
  4  from test;

RESULT
-----------------------------
FRL_Lines_PL.FRL_ATTRIBUTE_09

SQL>
```